# Adding multiple rows to a table in docx files with OpenXML

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, openxml

I am using TemplateEngine.Docx, Template engine for generating Word docx in Visual Studio for C#. Basically I am trying to add multiple rows to a table in an edited word document using a for loop. However when I loop through the if statement it will just rewrite the data that was just read. Here is my code:

```
if (fieldName == "examrubric")
            {

                for (; ; )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("To enter a row to the tabel type 'yes'\n");
                    string choice = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (choice == "yes")
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter a value for the question number:\n");
                        string qnum = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter a value for what the question is out of:\n");
                        string score = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter a value for how much was scored:\n");
                        string qscore = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter a value for score:\n");
                        string score2 = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the total mark:\n");
                        string total = Console.ReadLine();


                        valuesToFill = new Content(
                                       new TableContent("examrubric")
                                       .AddRow(
                                       new FieldContent("qnum", qnum),
                                       new FieldContent("score", score),
                                       new FieldContent("qscore", qscore),
                                       new FieldContent("score2", score2),
                                       new FieldContent("total", total)));
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following code to write data to the docx file in the loop to avoid the rewrite the data .

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            File.Copy("test1.docx", "OutputDocument.docx");
            Console.WriteLine("To enter a row to the tabel type 'yes'\n");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();
            Content valuesToFill = new Content(new TableContent("Team Members Table"));
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                if (choice == "yes")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a value for the Name:\n");
                    string name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a value for the Role:\n");
                    string role = Console.ReadLine();
                    valuesToFill.Tables.First().AddRow(
                            new FieldContent("Name", name),
                            new FieldContent("Role", role)) ;
                    
                   
                }

            }
            using (var outputDocument = new TemplateProcessor("OutputDocument.docx").SetRemoveContentControls(true))
            {
                outputDocument.FillContent(valuesToFill);
                outputDocument.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
```

Tested result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried this but it said that there  was Field Content Control 'xxxxxx' was not found in the word document.

Comment: @Kevin Liu, the error means that you need to add the correspond content control for your code. You could refer to the link [TemplateEngine.Docx](https://github.com/UNIT6-open/TemplateEngine.Docx)